# How can I search for a specific feature in vim?

Tags: vim

In another thread about Vim, someone suggested `ci"` in order to change an entire string when the cursor is on the string.

I found this very interesting and wanted to read about it in Vim's help system. Yet, a `:help ci` brought me to `copyindent` (which is obviously not what I was after) and a `:help ci"` told me that there's no help for it.

So, how would I go about searching for help on this specific feature? 
Also, how do you generally search for features you know they're there but forgot the name of it.

Thanks / Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate `:h helpgrep`.

Comment: Err... How did that help here?

Answer (score 5):

The trouble is that you have to understand a lot of how vim works before you can use the help system effectively.

In your case, the answer is that there is no `ci"` command. However, there is a `c` command and indeed, `:help c` will send you to the correct topic. This will tell you about `c{motion}`. Think of the `i"` part as parameters or modifiers to the `c` command. Other modifiers of the `c` command are, for example, `w` which will **c**hange a **w**ord or `$` which will change the rest of the line.

To answer your question: You can look stuff like that up by trying the first character of the command you were given. If that brings up a help topic, the topic should also explain what modifiers you can use with the command. In this case, it will tell you about `{motion}`. Place the cursor on that and hit <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> to see what a `motion` is.

Comment: beat me to it.  note the difference between the single-letter-commands and the ones that are preceeded with `:`.

Comment: ;-) Good point. The colon makes a huge difference.